# Update a column with averages values in SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-update

I'm trying to update a column (avgVal) by averaging the last 3 values of another column (values). Right now, avgVal averages the last 2.

```
id     values     avgVal
1        2.0        2.0    // average of 2
2        3.0        2.5    // average of 2 and 3
3        4.0        3.5    // average of 3 and 4
4        5.0        4.5    // average of 4 and 5
```

And I would like:

```
id     values     avgVal
1        2.0        2.0    // average of 2
2        3.0        2.5    // average of 2 and 3
3        4.0        3.0    // average of 2, 3 and 4
4        5.0        4.0    // average of 3, 4 and 5
```

The best I could get was :

```
UPDATE f16 SET avgVal= AVG(values) OVER (ORDER BY id ASC BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

But window function doesn't work here.
Please, any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
update f16
    set avgval = (select avg(f2.val)
                  from (select f2.*
                        from f16 f2
                        where f2.id <= f.id
                        order by f2.id desc
                        fetch first 3 rows only
                       ) f2
                 );
```

This is probably not the most efficient method.  But without a database tag, it is hard to suggest anything else.

Given that your last question was about MariaDB, the above does not work in MariaDB.  Instead, you can use a `join`:

```
update f16 join
       (select f16.*,
               avg(val) over (order by id
                              rows between 2 preceding and current row
                             ) as avgval_3
        from f16
       ) f2
       on f16.id = f2.id
    set f16.avgval = f2.avgval_3;
```

Comment: Thank you! You saved me once again today. You're right for the database, I will add it next time. I couldn't use your first solution because of the FROM but the second worked like a charm! You're a star

Answer (score 1):

This could also work, you have already average for last 2, you can use that to calculate the new average:

```
UPDATE      f16
LEFT JOIN   f16 t on t.id = f16.id-2
SET         f16.avgVal = IF(t.values IS NULL, f16.avgVal, (f16.avgVal*2+t.values) / 3)
```

Without knowing you dataset and indexes, it is hard to guess performance, compare with other answer's solution using EXPLAIN. This should for for all SQL, I think.